# Rotation about axis of rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, rigid-body-dynamics

Consider a rigid body rotating about a given axis then each of its particle is undergoing  a circular motion.  Then which is the force that provides centripetal acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

The body only keeps its form while rotating due to interatomic forces. Otherwise each part would follow straight line trajectories.

That are the centripetal forces that allow a centripetal acceleration.